# Why `blocked task` errors appear on reboot?

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, reboot

When I restart or shutdown my laptop,

```
/dev/sda4: clean, 214843/1136688 files, 1684332/4553472
```

blocks appears on the screen and then other messages appear gradually. On top of that, I can not use the keyboard, the only button I can use is power button.

How can I fix this problem? In my laptop I have both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, dual boot. At first this `/dev/sda4: clean.....`  messages has been shown when I installed Ubuntu, and restarted it. Since then, it happens daily to my laptop.

Please share your help with me. I have searched this problem from google; Askubuntu, other ubuntu forums, etc. and it was not helpful enough.
A picture that is with messages is here.
[image: dev/sda4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by updates. I checked **Software Updater** in order to know if there are any new things for my Ubuntu or not. After checking, `/dev/sda4: clean, 214843/1136688 files, 1684332/4553472` appears in few seconds then disappears